# perl - help fetching an additional column with dbi call

Tags: perl, hash

How do I grab another column from a fetchrow_hashref?

For example, my original sub routine returned one value.

```
 sub get_val
    {
      undef $/;
      open (my $FH, "< tst.sql") or die "error can't open this file $!";
      my $sth= $dbh->prepare(<$FH>) ||
          die ("Cannot connect to the database: ".$DBI::errstr."\n");
      $sth->execute;
      close $FH;
      my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
      $sth->finish;
      return $row->{COL1};
      print $row;
    }
```

I altered my sql, so now I'm getting 2 values in return and want to fetch COL2

```
COL1     COL2
------   -------
1        A
```

Here is where I call by get_val:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
      $abc{oracle_dbi_connect},
      $abc{usr},
      $abc{pw},
      {AutoCommit => 0,RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0}) || die ("Cannot connect to the database: ".$DBI::errstr."\n");
my $val = get_val();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

I probably would then want to assign COL2 results to a new $val2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure getting `COL2` is as simple as using `$row->{COL2}` instead of `$row->{COL1}` (as you had in your code). So, make your `get_val` function return two values:

```
return @$row{'COL1', 'COL2'};
```

and in the calling function:

```
my ($val, $val2) = get_val();
```